# easiest way to add missing rows in R

Tags: r

I have the following table that I generate via a table/cumsum command.

```
> temp
   numCars
18       1
17       2
16       8
15      18
14      25
13      29
12      42
11      55
10      70
9      134
8      160
7      172
6      177
5      180
3      181
2      181
1      181
0      181

 temp <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 8L, 18L, 25L, 29L, 42L, 55L, 70L, 134L, 160L,                                             
 172L, 177L, 180L, 181L, 181L, 181L, 181L), .Dim = c(18L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(                               
     c("18", "17", "16", "15", "14", "13", "12", "11", "10", "9",                                              
     "8", "7", "6", "5", "3", "2", "1", "0"), "numCars"))
```

As you can see the row with name 4 is missing. What's the easiest R way to fill it in where the value should be the value of the number lower (in this case 181).

I understand I can do this with a messy for loop where I can go in, size it, create a new DF, then put in any blank values. I'm just wondering if there's a better way?

Here's the table code:

```
cohortSizeByMileage <- data.matrix(cumsum(rev(table(cleanMileage$OdometerBucket))))
colnames(cohortSizeByMileage) <- "numCars"
```

Comment: rbind and order? `rbind(temp, '4' = 181)[as.character(18:0), , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @rawr, in this case yes, but I want it to work for any missing number from 1 up to the max. 0 will always be there.

Comment: add the table code. you can probably convert to factors so that all the levels will still remain even if counts are 0

Comment: @rawr,  here's the table code. But remember, I don't want it to be 0, I want it to take the lower level value?

Comment: I always write custom code for this type of problem

Comment: @Alex: I agree - I do too -- but by asking you might see a new way to do that. For example, I wasn't aware of na.locf in the zoo package until I saw the solution. Now I know it :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create the row names as column from the original dataset 'temp', based on the minimum and maximum value of row number in temp, another dataset ('df2') was created,  `merge` or `left_join` the datasets, and fill the `NA` elements using `na.locf` from `library(zoo)`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(numCars=temp[[1]], rn1=as.numeric(row.names(temp)))
df2 <- data.frame(rn1= max(df1$rn1):min(df1$rn1))
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
left_join(df2, df1) %>%
        mutate(numCars= na.locf(numCars,fromLast=TRUE ))
#   rn1 numCars
#1   18       1
#2   17       2
#3   16       8
#4   15      18
#5   14      25
#6   13      29
#7   12      42
#8   11      55
#9   10      70
#10   9     134
#11   8     160
#12   7     172
#13   6     177
#14   5     180
#15   4     181
#16   3     181
#17   2     181
#18   1     181
#19   0     181
```

Comment: Hi, this worked great -- I don't think you need the temp[[1]] rather than just temp in the first df but I get the idea. marking this complete.

Comment: @user1357015 It is just to extract the column to create a new dataset or else create another column in the existing dataset.